# vim html auto close tag, different extension file

Tags: autocomplete, vim, omnicomplete

I'm using [HTML AutCloseTag](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2591) and it works perfectly in files with .html extension. But I'm using templating and files are named with php extension, then auto close tags doesn't works.

In my vimrc file I changed

```
autocmd FileType html,markdown setlocal omnifunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
```

to

```
autocmd FileType html,markdown,php setlocal omnifunc=htmlcomplete#CompleteTags
```

But it not resolve the problem.

I need extra configuration?

thanks a lot.

Comment: The line you have edited is not related to that plugin at all. Try `:set ft=php.html`.

Comment: thanks @romainl, I tried to do that, but it doesn't works.
when I put this in vinrc file, appears a problem with PIV bundle.

Comment: Thankfullnes is always welcome, however as for writing guidelines it is more proper good practice in Stack Exchange to leave them out of the post. Your question was usefull, thanks! You can edit it that line and then erase my comment. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 4):

The documentation already said, to add support for xhtml and xml, add

```
au FileType xhtml,xml so ~/.vim/ftplugin/html_autoclosetag.vim
```

So, for your question, the solution is to simply add this line in vimrc:

```
au FileType php so ~/.vim/ftplugin/html_autoclosetag.vim
```

Or use the specific path of this plugin if you use Pathogen to install plugins.